# Is Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP still supported?

Tags: windows-xp, updates, internet-explorer-8

Can anyone confirm if Internet Explorer 8 will continue to receive updates on Windows XP? I know that XP is now EOL but does that mean that IE8 on XP will no longer receive security updates either?

On [Microsoft's site](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=internet%20explorer&Filter=FilterNO) it says that IE follows the Support Lifecycle of its parent Major Product:

[image]

XP came with IE6, whereas IE8 was released with Windows 7 (and brought to XP later). So it's hard to tell if it is supported or not (and on what platform).

Comment: You answered your own question IE updates on XP will not be released

Comment: Office is not a component of the OS but IE is.  The only update I am aware being released is MSE signature updates no for MSE I product updates will be released (I.e engine updates )

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please explain how you know that IE8 will not receive updates on XP? As you can tell its a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Because the website itself says the component support life cycle is connected to the lifecycle of the OS itself...

Comment: "Internet Explorer 8 is also no longer supported" [Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/eos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article at Computerworld](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9246877/US_CERT_urges_XP_users_to_dump_IE), the answer is **no, IE8 on Windows XP will not continue to receive updates**.

> Because Microsoft ties support for Internet Explorer (IE) to the underlying operating system's end date, people running Windows XP will also not receive patches for IE7 or IE8, although others, including customers running the same browsers on Windows Vista and Windows 7, will continue to receive fixes.

This is also confirmed by [this post from a Microsoft support engineer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/lifecycle-internet-explorer-8/2d64f20f-7801-4636-82be-456302181b37?msgId=884a824f-f61a-4d13-992a-5933e3acb58f):

> Internet Explorer 8 will be supported as long as the Windows version in which it's running is supported (e.g., until April 2014 for WinXP SP3 and until April 2017 for Vista SP2).

The rationale seems to be that IE8 for XP is not the exact same product as IE8 for Vista or Windows 7. Therefore, patches and updates released for the latter may not necessarily apply to the former, due to architectural differences between the OS versions.

Comment: Thankyou, This makes it much clearer. Although its not the news I wanted to hear! Thanks.